# Java, a return method which I cannot understand

Tags: java, string, get, int, return

```
public String getCar(int marvel){

}
```

I cannot understand how to correctly write the return method. I am pretty much new at Java and tried searching for it on google everywhere, but couldn't find an example like that. I cannot return marvel, because it has to be from type String. Well yea, what else could I possibly return in this case or should I convert marvel into String? Thanks in advance!

Comment: We can't know what the method is supposed to do. All we know is that it must return a String. A valid (technically) implementation would be `return "hello";`. Is it the right string to return? We don't know, since you haven't said what the method should do. The method seems to indicate that you need to return a car, and that the car to return depends on the marvel passed as argument. But we have no idea of what a marvel is or how and where to find its car.

Comment: Well before that I have public String getCar()(NOTE: without int marvel in the brackets) in another class  which returns car from type String. Now I have to write the same method with (int marvel) in the brackets in another class. So yea I am not sure what is supposed to happen

Answer (score 0):

You can't `return` a `int` value here because the method's `return` type is `String`. So you can either `return` the `String` value of the `int` marvel like here,

```
public String getCar(int marvel) {
    return String.valueOf(marvel);
}
```

Or change your method's `return` type to `int` and then `return` then `int` value like here,

```
public int getCar(int marvel) {
    return marvel;
}
```

Comment: Thank you! I solved my problem with the first code! Thanks a lot for your time.